# Event Sourcing - advice on multi stream projection needed

Tags: event-sourcing

As a learing excercise I am trying to rewrite one of my work projects as an event sourced system.
What I am trying to achieve is a full possiblity to check the state at any given moment (like time travel).

The question will cover my attempts in writing a projection that spans multiple streams. Since I have doubts on all of them I'd like to ask for some advice.

## Domain

Let's start with the domain and my requirements. It will be an easy system for sceduling and managing tasks for a group of workers.

user should be allowed to:

- create new *task* with a given date and time
- reschedule a *task* to a new date and time
- view a calendar with the tasks for a given week

Additionally my system should be able to:

- show full history of *task* alterations (creation, assignment, reschedule, comments added, etc.)
- show state of a weekly calendar for any given date and time

Basically, I'd like to have calendar view with a datetime picker that would allow me to see the callendar state at any selected moment.

I also made a non functional assumption that the system would be read heavy, so I'd like to be able to read weekly calendar view in a fast way, preferably from already materialized data in document-like storage.

## Problem

I am unsure how to introduce a projection that would allow me to aggregate all *tasks* scheduled for a given week (and still be able to time travel).

I find event `TaskRescheduled` problematic and also I have my doubts then it comes to designing a projection to feed the weekly calendar view. I have few ideas, but i can't make up my mind which would be the correct one for me to pick.

## Events and aggregations

Since I want to track whole history of any single *Task* I have designed set of events:

```
TaskCreated
- TaskId
- Description
- StartDateTime
- Duration
- ...

TaskRescheduled
- TaskId
- StartDateTime
- Duration

...few other events that are not important...
```

Each *task* events are stored in separate streams. Stream Id is equal to `TaskId`.

## Possible solutions

I am skipping the obvious synchronous projection that reads all events and aggregates them when when I am requesting a callendar view for possible performance reasons and would like to solve it in async way.

### 1. Async projection on all task streams

An asynchronous projection could be created that would listen to both `TaskCreated` and `TaskRescheduled` across all task streams. It can react to those events and store the results in a table like:

```
| TaskId   | StartDateTime | Duration | Description | 
|----------|---------------|----------|-------------|
```

From here each time the calendar view is rendered I can make a query and filter tasks for the period I am interested in.

The problem I see with this approach is that it stores the current state only. I have no easy way to go back in time and ask for a state from 2 days ago.
I would have to can run a synchronous projection again on all events that that would quickly become unusable approach.

I could introduce a snapshot here, but frankly, I do not see an easy way to snapshot this kind of data.

### 2. Raise multiple events to both task and weekly streams

Another approach is to alter my domain code and make it aware of more than just a *task* stream. For instance rescheduling a task may look like this:

```
RescheduleTask(taskId, newStartDateTime, newDuration)
{
    var taskStreamId = GetStreamIdForTask(taskId);
    var task = GetCurrentAggregateofTask(taskId);

    // raise event for task stream
    RaiseEvent(taskStreamId, new TaskRescheduled(...))

    // raise event for previous week
    var oldWeekStreamId = GetStreamIdForWeekContainingDate(task.StartTime)
    RaiseEvent(oldWeekStreamId, new TaskRemovedFromWeek(...))

    // raise event for new week    
    var newWeekStreamId = GetStreamIdForWeekContainingDate(newStartTime)
    RaiseEvent(newWeekStreamId, new TaskAddedToWeek(...))
}
```

That way I have separate streams for each week, so querying the historical states is easy.

One thing I am not sure here, if this kind duplicating events isn't some kind of anti pattern.
We can correlate both weekly events to the task event to mark them as part of the same logical transaction (like adding *CausedByEvent* filed to the event store).

Other thig that bugs me, is that this clutters the domain code and make is more complicated than it needs to be. I can fix this by extracting it to additional intermediate projection

Moreover, I need to know up front that I need the weekly calendar streams. Raising those events direclty in domain code would make adding this feature problematic (in case I did not know I need a weekly callendar view).

### 3. Async intermediate projection to produce events for weekly streams

To solve the issue with too much code in the domain method we can extract some code logic to additional projection that would listen to `TaskRescheduled` and produce both `TaskRemovedFromWeek` and `TaskAddedToWeek` events.

A pseudo code for such a projection may look like this

```
Handle(TaskRescheduled event)
{
    var oldStartDateTime = GetOldStartTimeOfTask(event.TaskId)

    // raise event for previous week
    var oldWeekStreamId = GetStreamIdForWeekContainingDate(oldStartDateTime)
    RaiseEvent(oldWeekStreamId, new TaskRemovedFromWeek(...))

    // raise event for new week    
    var newWeekStreamId = GetStreamIdForWeekContainingDate(event.StartDateTime)
    RaiseEvent(newWeekStreamId, new TaskAddedToWeek(...))
}
```

Since this projection requires knowledge of the old start date we need to store it somehow. It is required to intruduce additional storage. For instance a table like this:

```
| TaskId   | StartDateTime | 
|----------|---------------|
```

I have a gut feeling that this solution is overcomplicated and would introduce more harm in a long run. I know that it is acceptable to raise additional events from a projection (i.e. EventStoreDB has a special API for this) but I am not sure if this is still acceptabe if we require additional storage to be accessed.

### 4. Enrich the TaskRescheduled event with more data

Finally one of the simplest solutions is to enrich TaskRescheduled event with info obout previous schedule.

```
TaskRescheduled
- TaskId
- NewSchedule
   - StartDateTime
   - Duration
- OldSchedule
   - StartDateTime
   - Duration
```

With this solution my projection responsible for weekly view can update both weeks in our storage:

```
void Handle(TaskRescheduled event)
{
    // remove task form old week
    var oldWeek = GetWeekContainingDate(event.NewSchedule.StartDateTime)
    oldWeek.RemoveTask(event.TaskId)

    // add task to new week
    var newWeek = GetWeekContainingDate(event.NewSchedule.StartDateTime)
    newWeek.AddTask(event.TaskId)
}
```

This is simple, but adds extra data that seems to not be meaningfull in the event.

Also if someone raised a TaskRescheduled event with invalid old date I have my week views in invalid state, since a task may be in 2 weeks simultaneously. In previous solutions with separated streams I could fix the code, drop the weekly view streams and recreate them. Here I do not have such a possiblity.

Moreover, the problem I am solving may appear again for different views and events so I will be forced to add extra data to more events. For instance adding `TaskReassigned` would yeld similar problems if I would have a separate projection for each of my worker views.

## The question

Is there a well-known solution for this weekly view projection problem?
I think this kind of relationship is a common problem and I'd like to hear some advice on how it can be solved. I am overthinking the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Projections will generally require some storage, so the objection to #3 melts away.

It's also worth noting that #2 and #4 (in different ways) move the intermediate projection into the write-side of the system; this clutters the domain code, but it does have the advantage of potentially stronger consistency (though how much of a win that is, is up to you).

One question to ask is "how often will I need to reconstruct the state as of a certain point in time?"  A question rarely asked that's expensive/slow to answer might not be worth trying to make cheaper/faster (pre-baking the projection to answer that question might cost more in effort or operations (a database isn't actually free...) than the benefit).

#1 and #3 are the broad solutions.  If you expect to frequently need to answer that question, then I'd choose #3 (or if consistency dictated either #2 or #4), otherwise #1 is probably sufficient.

Note that one major benefit of event sourcing is that you can change your mind later.  You can migrate from any of these choices to the other with just another projection (possibly one keeping arbitrary state).